# How do you make an xmlhttprequest in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write an javascript basic jquery like library and I'm attempting to write a function that will make a ajax like call using the xmlhttprequest object but it seems to not be running the if statments.

At first I had tried the onLoad function but no luck as well as the addEventListener which I'm not gettin an error but I'm not gettin an response either

This is where I build the function

```
request: (type, url, cb) => {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.addEventListener("load",function (response) {
                if (xhttp.responseText != 200) {
                    console.log("Error" + xhttp.status)
                }
                else {
                    return cb(response)
                }
            })
            xhttp.open(type, url, true);
        }
```

This where I call the function

```
var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=apiKey";

legion().request("GET", url, function (res) {

    console.log(res)

})
```

I'm expecting to get the response then send that data back in cb function

Comment: `if (xhttp.responseText != 200) {` The `responseText` should be `status`.

Comment: And the `return` will do you no good, because it's asynchronous.

Comment: And you didn't `.send()` the request. Opening it doesn't automatically send it.

Comment: so there should be no return?

Comment: It should just be `cb(response);`. The `return` doesn't do anything useful, but it doesn't break anything either.

Comment: The main problems are checking the wrong property and never calling `xhttp.send()`

Comment: prefer to use fetch => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Alright thanks It is working now.

Comment: You may want to scrub your API key so you don't go over your rate limit from others calling.